# Poupulate a Javascript array of individual dates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to populate an array of individual dates 60 days formatted.  If I entered it by hand it would look: like unavailableDates = ["12-4-2015","13-4-2015", . . ."11-5-2015"]. I will use this array else ware in the function.  This is an excerpt of my function that is not working.  I am not sure what I am misunderstanding.

```
    function unavailable(date) {
        var unavailableDates = [];
        var i = Date.today().toString('dd-MM-yyyy');
        var j = Date.today().addDays(60).toString('dd-MM-yyyy');
        while(i < j){   
        unavailableDates.push(new date(i)).toString('dd-MM-yyyy');
        i=new Date(i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1));
        }
        }
```

Comment: Where does `Date.today()` come from?

Answer (score 1):

your code has bugs:

`Date.today` is not function,

and `toString` method doesn't get formatted date you must format it in your code

Try this function:

```
function unavailable(days) {
    var i = Date.now();
    var unavailableDates = [];
    var j = i + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    while(i < j) {
      var d=new Date(i);
      unavailableDates.push(d.getDate() + '-' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + (d.getYear() + 1900));
      i += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    }
    return unavailableDates;
}

var numOfDays = 30;
var populated = unavailable(numOfDays);

console.log(populated); // ["12-4-2015","13-4-2015", . . ."11-5-2015"]
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets me going again.

Answer (score -1):

Either move the declaration of unavailableDates outside the function or return unavailableDates within the function to be assigned.

Based on scope, unavailableDates is only usable within the function, as you have written it.

You should try something like ...

```
var unavailableDates = [];
```

... and separately ...

```
function unavailable(date) {
    var i = Date.today().toString('dd-MM-yyyy');
    var j = Date.today().addDays(60).toString('dd-MM-yyyy');
    while(i < j) {
      unavailableDates.push(new date(i)).toString('dd-MM-yyyy');
      i = new Date(i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1));
    }
}
```